# Rails - Spree language in login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to use spanish as the frontend language in Spree. Almost everything is translated but the login and everything related to it aren't. The `es-CL.yml` [file](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_i18n/blob/master/config/locales/es-CL.yml) has the translations on it. It is a devise problem?

This is the code I'm using to  only translate the frontend.

```
module Spree
  class FrontendConfiguration < Preferences::Configuration
    preference :locale, :string, :default => 'es-CL'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Login page is not part of frontend as it comes from spree_auth_devise (https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise). You need to check its working over there.